# Use standalone executable JAR as a plugin for site maven goal

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml

I have an executable JAR-with-dependencies file which makes some operations on tests' reports.

I keep it in my project and would like it to be executed right after Maven 'site' goal is finished. 
Is there any proper way to do this? 
Maybe by adding a path to that file somewhere here?

```
 <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>my JAR file</groupId>
                <artifactId>traceability-matrix-builder</artifactId>
                <path> path to the file</path>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Easy enough:

1. Add the exec plugin and specify the path to executable jar:

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
           <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.3.2</version>
           <configuration>
               <executable>java</executable>
               <arguments>
                   <argument>-jar</argument>
                   <argument>traceability-matrix-builder-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar</argument>
               </arguments>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```
2. Add the goal after the site:

   mvn site exec:exec

That's it!